# MongoDB lost in droplet Digital Ocean

Tags: django, mongodb, digital-ocean, droplet

I've built a Django web app on a droplet of Digital Ocean. The app was working fine. Today, when I opened my web app, no data appeared. I had a look at the droplet (server), and I found that all data in my `mongodb` is lost. Especially, when I type `show dbs` in mongodb shell, it said:

`DB_HAS_BEEN_DROPPED  0.000GB`

Then I rebooted the server, and it worked again. The collections come back but only old data is available. New data, that I've been collected in recent days, is lost.
I faced a similar problem before. For that time, my process running mongodb was even turned off.

I suspect that my droplet was hacked by someone. Is that correct or that's the problem of mongodb? I also curious about security policy of Digital Ocean because when I set up a server one month ago, they sent me a message telling me that the server had strange outgoing traffic, and they locked my server just one day after setting up.

Thanks.

Comment: It's been a while since people learned to close access to the db from the wild: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/mongodb-databases-held-for-ransom-by-mysterious-attacker/ Check logs, ensure it listens to internal interfaces only.

Answer (score 1):

Set up MondoDB to listen on address `127.0.0.1` (or `localhost`) only so it's not open to the world.

See here for more details: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/administration/configuration/#security-considerations

Comment: I have ``127.0.0.1` set by default, but I'm going to run mongod with authentication option. Thanks.